# AWS VPC peering not working when same subnet is used for another service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, subnet

Here is what happening:

- Created ECS fargate cluster A and service/tasks inside in VPC-A(example).
- Created MSK Kafka cluster in another VPC B (example).
- Created peering connection and route table updated too.

**All works fine so far, but,**

- Now, I created another ECS fargate cluser B and service/tasks inside it, in VPC-A as well.
- But the application seems not be able to connect with MSK kafka cluster, the same which was working for cluster A (which still works!)

Cluster service B has same security group as cluster service A.

The logs for the application says this:

```
2020-05-05 15:40:11[2020-05-05 13:40:11,737] [1] [ERROR] Unable connect to "example-1.dummy-kafka-stage.ssss.c2.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:9092": [Errno 110] Connect call failed ('172.31.30.5', 9092)
[2020-05-05 13:40:11,737] [1] [ERROR] Unable connect to "example-1.dummy-kafka-stage.ssss.c2.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:9092": [Errno 110] Connect call failed ('172.31.30.5', 9092)
```

VPC peering is active, and the image below is of its route table in VPC peering tab:
[image]

Here is the VPC subnet route table, which are configured too (example of one such subnet in the image below):
[image]

Any idea as to what might be happening?

Comment: how is the inbound whitelisting done on MSK security group ? is it done by whitelisting VPC A security grp or entire VPC/subnet range right ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added to both VPCs route tables?

Both subnets will need to understand how to route to each other

Comment: sorry, didnt get it? I guess so, as if that was not the same then how come its working for one service already isnt it?

Comment: So to confirm the Fargate clusters, same subnets too? Or at least the subnets are using the same route tables?

Comment: I have also put the screenshot of peering connections route table.

Comment: Fargate cluster service using same subnets and of course the same VPC.

Comment: Might be worth enabling https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html to see whether its leaving the instance and if so and which side the reject is on

Comment: I have enabled flowlogs on both the vpcs but as its new to me, not sure what to see there.

Comment: I think one clue is from the unable to connect message `Connect call failed ('172.31.30.5', 9092)` where it knows to resolve hostname to an ip.

Comment: Formats can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html#flow-log-records